# C Language: How to use Macro as a decorator?

Tags: c, macros

I have a handmade profiler for C program running on ARM embedding systems. It's a "invasive" one, which means every time I want to profile a function `f()`, I need to add some code in the very beginning and end of the function, like:

```
int f(int a, int b) {
  BeginProfiling("f");
  ...
  EndProfiling();
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way? I mean, if I'm using Python I would definitely use a decorator. Is there a better solution using C Macro to have a decorator-like register mechanism? I would like the code as following:

```
__PROFILING__
int f(int a, int b) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Not as a decorator. But that macro could be made to expand into the initialization code when required, and placed *inside* the function. You'd need a pair, however. `ZC_PROFILING_STRAT` and `ZC_PROFILING_FINISH`.

Comment: The only idea I have is to write macro when function is called

Comment: @StoryTeller - more details?

Comment: @PeterJ - Do you really think that he does not know elementary macro directives?

Comment: So what is the difference between his `BeginProfiling` and your macro? I think he knows how to compile conditionally and how to wrap it in the macro. @StoryTeller I though that `ZC_PROFILE.....` is a special mechanism I have never heard before.

Comment: @PeterJ - There is no difference. It only addresses the minor concern of having the profiling code there at all times (which the OP doesn't want, and therefore thinks of using macros at all, possibly to conditionally profile). `ZC_...` is an abbreviation of their name, instead of the reserved `__PROFILING__`

Comment: @StoryTeller maybe it is already the macro and compiles conditionally?

Comment: @PeterJ - Then the OP is free to ignore my comment, of course.